# Able to Connect to my EC2 Instance, but there's nothing there?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've been trying to connect to my EC2 Instance, and have been able to by 1.) finding my private key, 2.) making it not publicly viewable and 3.) connecting to my instance with the syntax `ssh -i file.pem ubuntu@publicDNS`. However when I connect I don't receive the Amazon Linux AMI prompt or gain access to any of the files. It just leaves me with a blank line under the command I just ran. Like this: 
`mbasile$ ssh -i file.pem ubuntu@publicDNS`
`|` 
Not sure what the issue is, but any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Should clarify this is a project worked on by someone prior to me so there should be files available. Thanks! -MB

Comment: check as well the security group allows accessing tcp port 22

Comment: Sounds like your seesion is hanging while attempting to connect to the instance. Make sure your security group allows for inbound SSH connection, and whatever machine is trying to connect to the EC2 instance allows for outbound SSH connection.

Comment: Thank you for the responses Gusto and Preston! I was able to edit my Security Groups to face my IP and access my Instance. Appreciate the help !